# Why Bootstrap uses vertical-align and text-center middle if isn't necessary at all?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why would bootstrap use `vertical-align: middle` and `text-align: center` in the button component, if isn't necessary:

e.g:

```
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.25;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
padding: .5rem 1rem;
font-size: 1rem;
border-radius: .25rem;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
```

Same as:

```
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.25;
white-space: nowrap;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
padding: .5rem 1rem;
font-size: 1rem;
border-radius: .25rem;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
```

In my understand, the attribute that is centering the text is the `padding`.

Thank you.

Comment: They aren't the same. The browser default for a button is `vertical-align: baseline`. You can see the difference here https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/YQXxya

Comment: They are the same visually speaking, there isn't any difference between buttons with vertical-align, text-center or without it.

Comment: they are not the same visually. Pay close attention, `middle` is not the same as `baseline` - it's off by at least a couple of pixels in the example I showed. Try adjusting the font size of the button https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/yXNoOY

Comment: as for `text-align`, I don't know. firefox, chrome, and safari all apply text-align: center by default for a button. I'm assuming there is a browser that doesn't, but if so, I don't know which one.

Comment: Confirming that they **are not the same**. Minor visual difference between the two. The word _text_ shifts up a couple pixels when `vertical-align: middle;` is applied.

Comment: Yep, you are right, the vertical-align changes the button - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwJMBa , but still, the `text-align` doesn't.